# SQL - How can I rewrite this request without many SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have the number of open requests for each month before the 1st of each month. I use ComboChart and my orange line is, at the moment, the average for the 6 past months, I want to change this data for the opened requests.

Exemple : for April, I have 2 new requests and 1 closed request and I want the total of the requests open before the April 1st.

The period is for 6 months before and the selected month.
It will be a plus if you can use PIVOT :-)

Here what I have so far

```
select top 1
(
    select count(d.id) AS nbEncours 
    FROM [diagrammes].[demandes] as d
    WHERE DateDiff(month, d.dateEnvoi, GETDATE()) >=7 AND
    ( (d.statut=1 OR d.statut=2 OR d.statut=3 OR d.statut=4 OR d.statut=7) OR ( DateDiff(month, d.dateApprobation, GETDATE()) <7) )
) AS nbEnCours_1,
(
    select count(d.id) AS nbEncours
    FROM [diagrammes].[demandes] as d
    WHERE DateDiff(month, d.dateEnvoi, GETDATE()) >=6 AND
    ( (d.statut=1 OR d.statut=2 OR d.statut=3 OR d.statut=4 OR d.statut=7) OR ( DateDiff(month, d.dateApprobation, GETDATE()) <6) )
) AS nbEnCours_2,
(
    select count(d.id) AS nbEncours
    FROM [diagrammes].[demandes] as d
    WHERE DateDiff(month, d.dateEnvoi, GETDATE()) >=5 AND
    ( (d.statut=1 OR d.statut=2 OR d.statut=3 OR d.statut=4 OR d.statut=7) OR ( DateDiff(month, d.dateApprobation, GETDATE()) <5) )
) AS nbEnCours_3,
(
    select count(d.id) AS nbEncours
    FROM [diagrammes].[demandes] as d
    WHERE DateDiff(month, d.dateEnvoi, GETDATE()) >=4 AND
    ( (d.statut=1 OR d.statut=2 OR d.statut=3 OR d.statut=4 OR d.statut=7) OR ( DateDiff(month, d.dateApprobation, GETDATE()) <4) )
) AS nbEnCours_4,
(
    select count(d.id) AS nbEncours
    FROM [diagrammes].[demandes] as d
    WHERE DateDiff(month, d.dateEnvoi, GETDATE()) >=3 AND
    ( (d.statut=1 OR d.statut=2 OR d.statut=3 OR d.statut=4 OR d.statut=7) OR ( DateDiff(month, d.dateApprobation, GETDATE()) <3) )
) AS nbEnCours_5,
(
    select count(d.id) AS nbEncours
    FROM [diagrammes].[demandes] as d
    WHERE DateDiff(month, d.dateEnvoi, GETDATE()) >=2 AND
    ( (d.statut=1 OR d.statut=2 OR d.statut=3 OR d.statut=4 OR d.statut=7) OR ( DateDiff(month, d.dateApprobation, GETDATE()) <2) )
) AS nbEnCours_6,
    (
    select count(d.id) AS nbEncours
    FROM [diagrammes].[demandes] as d
    WHERE DateDiff(month, d.dateEnvoi, GETDATE()) >=1 AND
    ( (d.statut=1 OR d.statut=2 OR d.statut=3 OR d.statut=4 OR d.statut=7) OR ( DateDiff(month, d.dateApprobation, GETDATE()) <1) )
) AS nbEnCours_7
```

The results is what I expect, but I think it can be improve. What I want is this

```
  4     5     6     7     8     9     10
 52     53   45    49    60    58     55
```

[Evolution of requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV2Iu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try converting each Select to a CASE statement that evaluates to 1 if the conditions are true and zero otherwise. Then SUM each case statement e.g. (pseudo-code, not actual SQL):

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN some logic = true THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS nbEnCours_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN some other logic = true THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS nbEnCours_2,
...
FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you.

Comment: No problem - glad I could help. Please could you tick my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @NickW. I would use `SUM(CASE...)` to simplify. Something like:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN dateEnvoiMonths >=7 AND (statut IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7) OR dateApprobationMonths < 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbEnCours_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dateEnvoiMonths >=6 AND (statut IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7) OR dateApprobationMonths < 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbEnCours_2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dateEnvoiMonths >=5 AND (statut IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7) OR dateApprobationMonths < 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbEnCours_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dateEnvoiMonths >=4 AND (statut IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7) OR dateApprobationMonths < 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbEnCours_4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dateEnvoiMonths >=3 AND (statut IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7) OR dateApprobationMonths < 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbEnCours_5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dateEnvoiMonths >=2 AND (statut IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7) OR dateApprobationMonths < 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbEnCours_6,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dateEnvoiMonths >=1 AND (statut IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7) OR dateApprobationMonths < 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nbEnCours_7
FROM (
        SELECT 
            DateDiff(month, dateEnvoi, GETDATE()) AS dateEnvoiMonths,
            DateDiff(month, dateApprobation, GETDATE()) AS dateApprobationMonths,
            statut
        FROM [diagrammes].[demandes]
    ) tmp
```

To avoid all the repetition you could maybe also replace the summing logic with a function. Something like this should work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [diagrammes].[openTicketsForMonth] (@monthIn INT, @dateEnvoiMonths DATETIME, @statut INT, @dateApprobationMonths DATETIME)
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN @dateEnvoiMonths >= @monthIn AND (@statut IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 7) OR @dateApprobationMonths < @monthIn) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
END

SELECT
    SUM([diagrammes].[openTicketsForMonth](7, dateEnvoiMonths, statut, dateApprobationMonths)) AS nbEnCours_1,
    SUM([diagrammes].[openTicketsForMonth](6, dateEnvoiMonths, statut, dateApprobationMonths)) AS nbEnCours_2,
    SUM([diagrammes].[openTicketsForMonth](5, dateEnvoiMonths, statut, dateApprobationMonths)) AS nbEnCours_3,
    SUM([diagrammes].[openTicketsForMonth](4, dateEnvoiMonths, statut, dateApprobationMonths)) AS nbEnCours_4,
    SUM([diagrammes].[openTicketsForMonth](3, dateEnvoiMonths, statut, dateApprobationMonths)) AS nbEnCours_5,
    SUM([diagrammes].[openTicketsForMonth](2, dateEnvoiMonths, statut, dateApprobationMonths)) AS nbEnCours_6,
    SUM([diagrammes].[openTicketsForMonth](1, dateEnvoiMonths, statut, dateApprobationMonths)) AS nbEnCours_7
FROM (
        SELECT 
            DateDiff(month, dateEnvoi, GETDATE()) AS dateEnvoiMonths,
            DateDiff(month, dateApprobation, GETDATE()) AS dateApprobationMonths,
            statut
        FROM [diagrammes].[demandes]
    ) tmp
```